# Flash AS3: Problems linking a class to a symbol, classpath not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, classpath, embed

Im having problems with classpaths.  I have used them before with "import" but I'm not able to link a class directly to symbol in the library.

I have a class **c:/myfolder/src/myclass.as** . *In prefernces > AS3 settings*, I have **c:/myfolder/** as default classpath.  I click linkage on the symbol and enter **src.myclass** .  When I click the checkmark, it says 'class not found'.  I am able to do: ***import src.myclass;**  and attach the class to an instance on th stage. That works fine, but thats not what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  In *preferences > AS3 settings* the folder **"c:\myfolder\"** was below **".\"**. Once I moved it above, it saw the definition normally.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird to use src as a package.  Typically you'd set your preferences to c:/myfolder/src then put your top level package in there, but...

Check and make sure your file MyClass looks like this:

```
package src {
  public class MyClass {
     ...
  }
}
```

If it doesn't then you need to make sure your package matches the directories under your source directory (c:/myfolders).

Also you probably need to include the fully qualified package on the embed tag.

Comment: This is the first I have heard that I need to do anything with the package in the embed code. I assume you mean the embed code in my flash develop project. Can you post a link or more info on that?